# Tools to plot time-series data

Tags: ubuntu, software-rec, charts

I have a time-series dataset that looks like this (a few thousands of entries spanning for a couple of years):

```
timestamp <TAB> items_added <TAB> items_removed
```

For example:

```
1286016527 10 70
```

I want to play with this data, draw it on a plot and do some ad-hoc analysis.

For this particular task I do not want to use gnuplot, rrdtool or R. These tools take some fiddling to get a good plot, and right now I need something more lazy and casual (it is a weekend after all).

Perhaps there is some nice web-service to do this?

Or more casual standalone tool that works on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel is built for this sort of stuff.

Open the file (either as a "Tab Separated Values" document) or use "Text To Columns" and knock yourself out.

I assume OpenOffice is capable of this as well.

Comment: Right, Excel (or OpenOffice or Google Documents). Does it understand UNIX Epoch timestamps?

Comment: Excel (or alike) is good (I will convert timestamps if needed, no problem). I'll even use it and solve my task at hand. But I want to find some specialized (but more casual than coding in R language) time series data analysis tool.